# Generics Casting

Tags: c#, generics

```
interface Base { ... }
class Sub : Base { ... }

class OtherBase<T> where T : Base { ... }
class OtherSub<T> : OtherBase<T> where T : Base { ... }

//...in some class
void Call<T>() where T : OtherBase<Base> { }

//...
Call<OtherSub<Sub>>(); //compile fails...
```

Seems like when using generics, the compiler won't cast a inner generic type (Base/Sub) in the 
generic type (OtherBase/OtherSub). Why does this happen?

**Update**:
Please also explain the difference between the above and the following (which works)

```
void Call<T>() where T : Base { }
//...
Call<Sub>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forbidding this behaviour (known as “generic variance”) is necessary because otherwise the following code would compile:

```
List<string> strlist = new List<string>();
List<object> objlist = strlist;
objlist.Add(42);
```

We’ve added a number to a list of strings. Not good. (Incidentally, the code would compile for *arrays* instead of `List`s because Java allowed this for some reason; however, this will raise a runtime exception.)

You can avoid this in your case though:

```
static void Call<U, T>(T x) where U : Base where T : OtherBase<U> { }
```

And call it like this:

```
Call(new OtherSub<Sub());
```

C# 4.0 furthermore provides [generic variance for interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). However, their use isn’t often necessary.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense with the given example, but still doesn't for the method Call. Can you also explain the difference between your example and "void Call<T>() where T : Base { }", "Call<Sub>()" Please?

Comment: @james True, my mistake. Fixed that. Your expanded question is completely unrelated to generic variance so there’s no reason why this shouldn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is linked to a concept called variance/covariance. In fact, if `A` inherits from `B`, `Class<A>` isn't a `Class<B>`.

See this example:

`Class<T>` exposes a public method `foo(T param)`

If `Class<A>` was a `Class<B>`, then a method  having a reference to `Class<B>` as a `Class<A>` and calling `foo(B param)` (with a `B` instance) would be calling `foo(A param)`. And `B` isn't a `A`.

In fact, `Class<A>` can inherit from `Class<B>` only if `T` is used as a return value only in `Class<T>`.

This is enforced in .NET 4 through the out keyword for generics interface. `Class<T>` could therefore implement `IClass<out T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Konrad has a good advice on how to fix your code. If you wanted to use C# 4's variance, you could do it like this:

```
interface IOtherBase<out T> where T : Base { }

class OtherBase<T> : IOtherBase<T> where T : Base { }
class OtherSub<T> : OtherBase<T> where T : Base { }

static void Call<T>() where T : IOtherBase<Base> { }
```

`Call<OtherSub<Sub>>()` would work then.